# PHP- Using FileIO: Problems where whitescreen occurs from a file read

Tags: php

I'm trying to get fileIO to work properly, but it is outputting a blank page. We cannot get it past this point in order to continue with the lab. The code sample is simple but as follows.

EDITED CODE

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
$fileInput = $_POST("fileInput");
$fileInputIn = fopen($fileInput, "r");
$output=fread($fileInputIn, filesize($fileInputIn));
echo "Your output is : ".$output;
fclose($fileInputIn)
?>
```

fileInput takes a filename from a html form of a input file with data attached. The data is in this format.

```
John Q Public.  123 Main Street.  Glens Falls, NY 12801.  
1500 units
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: fopen returns a resource handle... you want to echo whatever comes back from your fread() I would assume?

Comment: Yes, to get it past this point, as if only outputs a blank screen. The lab itself has more parts, but this seems to be the point of error. If it gets past this point I can do the rest of the lab fine, but the fact that it's white-screening here is the issue.

Comment: that's because you are echoing $fileInputIn, a resource handle...

Comment: use something like: `$output =  fread($fileInputIn, filesize($fileInputIn));` and then `echo "Your ouput is : " . $output;`

Comment: Tried it out, but no dice. Code still outputs a white screen @lovelace
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
$fileInput = $_POST("fileInput");
$fileInputIn = fopen("$fileInput", "r");
$output=fread($fileInputIn, filesize($fileInputIn));
echo "Your output is : ".$output;
fclose($fileInputIn);

Comment: little snag in your fopen, change fopen("$fileInput", "r"); to fopen($fileInput, "r"); no quotation marks around your $fileinput

Comment: Alright, changed that but the issue still persists. @lovelace Also thanks for your help so far.

Comment: bummer, it still doesn't work, good luck